# Bootstrap Carousel Issues, Bootstrap Version 5

Tags: button, iframe, carousel, toggle, bootstrap-5

I'm new at this, and I hardly know how to put this in the correct terms, but basically, I'm making a carousel using Bootstrap 5.

I was able to get the names to carousel toggle, but not the iframes.

kennethlarotyamat.github.io/html/project14v002.html

I was able to do it on a different version of this class project, but the "names carousel" toggles with bootstrap, and the iframes toggle with a javascript or jquery mechanism.

https://kennethlarotyamat.github.io/html/project14.html

I have no idea what to do.

I tried having the carousel toggle buttons target 2 different ids: #demo1 for the names carousel, and #demo2 for the iframes carousel.

i also tried wrapping a button tag around a button tag, so the button that targeted #demo1 (names) was wrapped around another button that targeted #demo2 (iframes).

neither worked.

Comment: I think that I got it to work:

kennethlarotyamat.github.io/html/project14v004.html